# Why can't I attach to docker container of mariadb?

Tags: docker, mariadb

Why can't I attach to docker container of mariadb?

```
$ docker run --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -d mariadb/server:10.1
<SKIPPED>
78cadba14946919a3d62e1c616e39e76508107d24c6c1b93da534d3a3eb09e2d

$ docker attach 78cadba14946
<HANG>
```

How to see parameters of this container?

---

Also I can't ssh to the container

```
$ docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" mariadbtest
172.17.0.2

$ ssh 172.17.0.2
<HANG>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker attach <container>` attaches your terminal stream to the container stdout/stderr. If the container sends nothing to these streams - you will see nothing after attaching to it. Try executing some statement in the database and see if anything appears.

As for `ssh`, normally containers do not have `ssh` in it. Use `docker exec -it <container> sh` instead.